# Can't seem to get a linecount from this file

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to read a file and find out how many lines are in it.
These are code snippets without the 'if' error handling.
...

```
int fd = -1;
struct stat buff;
char * logbuff;

fd = open("/home/path/to/test", O_RDONLY, 0);

fstat(fd, &buff);

logbuff = 
        (char*)mmap(
            NULL,                   //OS chooses address
            buff.st_size,           //Size of file
            PROT_READ,              //Read only
            MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED,    //copy on write
            fd,
            0
            );

const char * ch = &logbuff[0];
    for ( i = 0; i < buff.st_size; i++ ) {
        if ( ch[i] == '\n' ) {
            newlines++;

            cout << ch[i];
        }
    }

cout << "lines: " << newlines << endl;
```

I get 'lines: 0'

I have a

Comment: Click [edit] to finish your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's read the documentation for `MAP_ANON` and `MAP_ANONYMOUS`:

> #### MAP_ANON
>
> Synonym for MAP_ANONYMOUS.  Deprecated.
>
> #### MAP_ANONYMOUS
>
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.
>   The fd and offset arguments are ignored; however, some implementations  require
>   fd to be -1 if `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (or `MAP_ANON`) is specified, and portable applications
>   should ensure this.  The use of `MAP_ANONYMOUS` in conjunction with `MAP_SHARED` is
>   only supported on Linux since kernel 2.4.

So we can see that when we use `MAP_ANON`, the `fd` parameter is **ignored**! You actually are looking for `MAP_PRIVATE`:

> #### MAP_PRIVATE
>
> Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.  It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the `mmap()` call are visible in  the  mapped region.

Therefore, the call to mmap should be:

```
logbuff = mmap(NULL, buff.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

Additionally, you'll want to verify that the call to `mmap()` succeeds. To do that, make sure that the returned pointer is not `MAP_FAILED`.

Comment: Oh, I can only seem to pass one of those flags, not both. Thank you.

Comment: @user3816764: Yep. sorry about that. We only want `MAP_PRIVATE`. We can either do `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`. We can't do both.

Comment: Right, figured. Thanks very much, exactly what I was looking for. I'll mark that as the answer.